# Making the clusters fixed in place in K-Means

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, k-means, image-segmentation, steganography

I am doing image segmentation on black & white images using K-Means, I have K=2, where I need to determine the black area all the time and use it later for steganography purposes. The problem is when I run the code, the clusters change in index, the black area comes in index 0 once and on the other run comes in index 1.

Is there any way to have this fixed in place? And for multiple images too.
The code is written in Python using OpenCV library.

Comment: You could look at the intensities for the pixels in each of the clusters, then pick the one with the lowest intensities.

Comment: Is there any specific function you recommend?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation because you haven't specified what programming language you're using, what imaging library you're using, or anything else. Please [edit] your question to be more specific and allow an answer beyond vague concepts.

Comment: Ok, so you use `cv.kmeans`? Do you input a gray-scale image or a color image? A bit of reproducible code would help in answering (see [mre]). In any case, if you look for two clusters, you should get two values back in `centers`. The average of these two is the threshold value between the two clusters. Use `cv.threshold` (or just Python's `>` operator) to threshold your image at this value and be guaranteed an order.

Comment: Do note that the Otsu algorithm should give you better results in general for a single threshold (K=2 in a gray-scale image). Also, Otsu is reproducible (K-means potentially gives different answers depending on initialization) and much faster.